# Is it possible to run Teamcity on Linux and use Windows as a Build Agent?

Tags: teamcity

I would like to run Teamcity (with a build agent) in a Linux VM to handle our none-.net projects. But in the same breath I'd like to have a BuildAgent setup on a Windows server to handle all of the .net projects.

I can't think of any reasons why this wouldn't work but has anyone any experience and any ideas about the problems I might encounter before I spend too much real time on this?

Ta

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's fully supported.  TeamCity also knows which agents to route builds to.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very normal scenario and many project I know do this without any problems. Just make sure that for the builds' `Agent Requirements`, you properly direct the appropriate job to the appropriate agent. One criterion can be that `agent.os.name` should contain Windows or Linux etc.